# Hooking up JSON api to tableView without overloading

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, swift

i've created a simple API which retrieve all news from a database. However i'm confused on what is the best practice to retrieve all without using to much space? There is a looooot of news in this database and i guess it is bad for the user if it retrieve all of them and show them in the tableView. So i guess i need to make some kind of load more function to my tableView when you scroll to the button?

So far i've just made this function which retrieve all the news, but what will my initial step be in order to optimize this?

```
func getRecent(url: NSString) {

    let recentUrl = NSURL(string: url as String)
    var recentRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: recentUrl!)
    var recentData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(recentRequest, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)

    let jsonArray = JSON(data: recentData!)
    for (key: String, subJson: JSON) in jsonArray {
        // Create an object and parse your JSON one by one to append it to your array
        var newNewsObject = News(id: subJson["id"].intValue, title: subJson["title"].stringValue, link: subJson["url"].stringValue, imageLink: subJson["image_url"].stringValue, summary: subJson["news_text"].stringValue, date: getDate(subJson["date"].stringValue)) 
        recentArray.append(newNewsObject)
    }
    arrayNews.append(recentArray)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function which response news in some pagination if possible [Optional]

You can make a table view the paging size you want, like at a time 10 news to be posted, then the paging, then you can choose way like this

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1; 
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [newsArray count]+1;   
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (indexPath.row< newsArray.cout) {
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
        }
    }
    else {
          Cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"LoadingViewCell"];
          // add 10 more newsArray to the Array.
    }
}
```

Hope Help this to primary level.

HTH, Enjoy Coding !!